# Is soap failure causing lock time wait out

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, sockets, soap

I have socket programming which will receive data and thereafter run select,insert and finally do update statement. Finally within the socket connection I will call soap connection and send data over to the webservice. Below is just skeleton of my codes. In thread run after all the select,insert,update I call  callSoap(dataID,dataString);

I get this error at this line SOAPMessage soapACK = soapConnection.call(soapCalling(dataID,dataString), url); after this error then I tend to get lock wait timeout error at the update. I suspect this error is when the webservice link is down? How best can I overcome this issue and should I call a separate thread for the webservice ? Is there anything wrong in my calling of the soap ? Must I close it ?

```
SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
at sk1$ConnectionHandler.sendIncomingData(sk1.java:2753)
at sk1$ConnectionHandler.run(sk1.java:2057)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:649)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:327)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
... 3 more

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:649)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:327)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
at sk1$ConnectionHandler.sendIncomingData(sk1.java:2753)
at sk1$ConnectionHandler.run(sk1.java:2057)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```